# Class 'Controller' not found

Tags: yii

> Class 'Controller' not found in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\protected\controllers\AppsinfoController.php
> on line 4

указывает на это:

```
>     class AppsinfoController extends Controller
>     {
>       public function actionIndex()
>       {
>           $this->render('index');
>       }
>         public function loadModel($id)
>       {
>           $model=TAppsInfo::model()->findByPk($id);
>           if($model===null)
>               throw new CHttpException(404,'The requested page
> does not exist.');
>           return $model;
>       }
> }
```

Каковы могут быть причины?

Комментарии закончились пишу сюда: TAppsInfo.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

прописать

```
CController // а не Controller
```

- это все придется делать в каждом контроллере, совет сделать базовый контроллер

типа

```
   class СController extends Controller
    {
    $layout='//bla';
    $menu=array();
    $breadcrumbs=array();
}
```

и его юзать везде.

**//upd** ок.
Попробуй.

```
public function loadModel($id)
  {
      $model=TAppsШтащ::model()->findByPk($id); // что за русский язык?
      if($model===null)
          throw new CHttpException(404,'The requested page
does not exist.'); return $model; } }
```

И почему у тебя первая буква там **T** в модели реально есть буква **T** или ты ее просто так сюда списала?

Тут вариант то какой. Возможно что модель названа **TAppsInfo** а файл не так, т.е. может **appsInfo** посмотри на то как модель названа и какой файл.

**//upd**

ОК поверим что там есть

> TAppsInfo  TAppsImg TApps

Другие контролы с другими моделями нормально загружаются?

Comment: в конфиге модели загружаются?

Comment: опробуй и для этого контрола перегенерить crud

Comment: сгенерировала и даже контролер переписала с помощью crud, ничего(

Comment: все, пора в дурку. День сидела мучилась и мучила вас, а ошибка в конфиге, опечаталась в одной строке в подключении модуля, который обращается к этой модели.
Спасибо за помощь